Facebook Android SDK: number of standard install and activateApp events extremely low compared to what it should be
I think I implemented the Facebook Android SDK properly but when I check the number of events in Facebook Events Manager, I see a very low (and clearly wrong) number of installs compared to the number of ActivateApp events. See the picture below:

Why do I get such an inconsistent number of installs ?
Thanks for your help.
